# Positioning 3 images after fade one of them

Tags: jquery, css

Assume that we've 3 images in one row. When the second image will fade, third will take his position, analogic, when first will fade, second take first position and third take the second position. But I want to reach something like this. When any images will fade I want to put a white gap into position. Is it possible?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="https://service.pollstation.uk/img/users/us_1488800972.png" border="1" />
    <img src="http://forum.bladeandsoul.com.pl/download/file.php?avatar=446_1452981972.jpg" border="1" />
    <img src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/893/thumb-89303.gif" border="1" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add some code to put your question in place

Comment: Please include your CSS too. I see you're a student, so as a learning exercise, think about what you might need to get this to work - what's missing? What might you need to add in? Let us know what ideas you come up with - we're here to help, not to come up with the solution and write the code for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set `opacity` property of `image` to hide or unhide it on click event.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function(){
        if($(this).css('opacity') === '0')
          $(this).css('opacity', '1');
        else
          $(this).css('opacity', '0');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://service.pollstation.uk/img/users/us_1488800972.png" border="1"/>
<img src="http://forum.bladeandsoul.com.pl/download/file.php?avatar=446_1452981972.jpg" border="1"/>
<img src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/893/thumb-89303.gif" border="1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing it completely just fade it out so It'll keep it's place but doesn't show like this

```
$(this).fadeTo("slow", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('img').each(function(i){
    $(this).css({
      left: 210 * i   
    });
  });

  $("img").click(function(){
    var left = $(this).css('left');
    var that = this;
    $(this).fadeOut(500, function(){
      $(that).siblings('img').each(function(i){
        $(this).css({
          left: 210 * i   
        });
      });
      $(that).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
img { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://service.pollstation.uk/img/users/us_1488800972.png" border="1"/>
<img src="http://forum.bladeandsoul.com.pl/download/file.php?avatar=446_1452981972.jpg" border="1" style="left: 210px;"/>
<img src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/893/thumb-89303.gif" border="1" style="left: 210px;"/>
```

Hope this will help you.